# Storing polymoprhic data types into a unique_ptr vector

Tags: c++, vector, polymorphism, function-pointers, unique-ptr

I'm having issues trying to build a program using a Unique_ptr vector to hold data from multiple classes that are derived from the same base class.  I'm pretty sure the concept is correct, so I can avoid slicing my data, but I'm not sure what exactly I'm doing wrong here.  Also I'm not sure how I'm supposed to pass a unique_ptr to a function to read it or write it.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. (Edit, made the code actually comprehensible, sorry for that!)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;


class Base
{
public:
    Base();
    Base(int x, int y, string z) :Z(z), Y(y), X(x){}
    virtual void printstuff(){cout << X << Y << Z; system("pause"); }
    virtual ~Base(){}
protected:
    int X, Y;
    string Z;
};

class Derrived : public Base
{
public:
    Derrived();
    Derrived(int x, int y, string z, int a, int c) : Base(x, y, z), changeable(c), A(a){}
    virtual void printstuff(){cout << X << Y << Z << changeable << A;}
    int changeable;
    ~Derrived(){}
private:
    int A;
};

void otherfunction(vector<unique_ptr<Base>>&);

void main()
{
    vector<unique_ptr<Base>> array1;
    array1.emplace_back(new Derrived (1, 2, "check", 3, 5));
    otherfunction(array1);
    array1[0]->printstuff();
    system("pause");
}



void otherfunction(vector<unique_ptr<Base>>& var1)
{
    dynamic_cast<Derrived &>(*var1[0]).changeable = 3;
}
```

I want the output statement to be 3 for changeable, I'm getting an error C2664 for some reason so I'm not sure what exactly I'm doing wrong, as it doesn't reference a specfic line in my code (the line it references is line 600 of xmemory.h).  A copy of the actual code can be found here: [Link to the actual code.](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/546451cc5f03871e974f)

Update:  The code above compiles and runs properly, however the method is anything but safe and can result in serious errors throughout the program.  The program was completely written from the ground up using multiple standard arrays to hold individual classes instead of one vector storing multiple classes.

Comment: Lacks [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org).

Comment: Your code is invalid; For example `Class` is undefined, the prototype for `otherfunction` uses undeclared identifier `array1` , the supposed class definitions don't have semicolons ... it's important that you post the **exact** code that is giving you the error. Use copy and paste, dont' type something out that vaguely resembles it.

Comment: the code in `otherfunction` should be `dynamic_cast<Derived &>(*var1[0]).changeable = 3;`  . An improved design would be for Base to have a virtual setter for setting `changeable` , as a good design should not involve you having to explicitly cast. Also `otherfunction` should take the vector by reference . passing `unique_ptr` by value will leave main's vector empty.

Comment: Also the [base class destructor should be virtual](http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/virtual-functions#virtual-dtors)

Comment: I've made the changes you guys suggested, sorry it was a bit sloppy, I was updating it from really confusing code without a compiler available, I'm at home now so I can actually ctrl-c + ctrl-v now.  The actual code I'm trying to get functional is linked at the bottom of my original text.  I'm still not able to get it working,  I'm specifically not allowed to have any code referring to changeable in the base class.

Comment: Stop guessing. `cout << array1[0]->printstuff` is certainly incorrect. `printstuff` is a member *function*;  not a variable.

Comment: Good catch, it's updated now, the code still gives me the same error though (C2664).  I'm not sure how to properly pass the vector by reference I tried this but it gives a compile error: `void otherfunction(vector<unique_ptr<Base>*>$ var1)`

Comment: `unique_ptr` does not support copy; you need to change `otherfunction` to pass the vector by reference. Actually you should always do this for vectors anyway. Why do so many people get this wrong?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to pass it by reference, like the proper syntax. `void otherfunction(vector<unique_ptr<Base>>& var1)` and `void otherfunction(vector<unique_ptr<Base>&> var1)` also aren't working.

Comment: show the exact error message, "C2664" doesnt mean much by itself

Comment: `Error 4 error C2664: 'void otherfunction(std::vector<int,std::allocator<_Ty>> &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>>' to 'std::vector<int,std::allocator<_Ty>> &' c:\users\richard\skydrive\cosc 1320\testapp\testapp\testapp.cpp 41 1 testapp`

Comment: The `testapp.cpp 41 1` at the end of the error message indicates that this error is on line 41 of `testapp.cpp`

Comment: Yeah the original error was probably due to not using dynamic_cast, I've updated everything now.  The error in the actual program that this is psuedocode for is not related to the position of the prototype though, since all classes are contained in the header before function declarations are made.  Changes to the code have turned the error into: `Error 2 error C2227: left of '->printstuff' must point to class/struct/union/generic type line 43 testapp`  and another error code stating that  'C2683: 'dynamic_cast' : 'std::unique_ptr<Base,std::default_delete<_Ty>>' is not a polymorphic type'

Comment: @Redklaw when I move the prototype then that error goes away ... and there are no other compilation errors besides `void main` and the one pointed out by WhozCraig.

Comment: you've been through several cycles now of: Post code, get an answer, say "oh that wasn't the real code" and edit the code. You are just wasting everyone's time until you **post the real code**.

Comment: The real code is posted, below the pseudocode, there's a link to gist... It's been there the whole time.  I don't want to post it here because it's obnoxiously long.  [Here's the link again](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/546451cc5f03871e974f)

Comment: what makes you think `dynamic_cast<Derrived &>(array1[0])` is legal code or even a good idea?  As WhozCraig **stop guessing** at code. That's not how you program.

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for how to post code, or see the link posted by Baum mit Augen.  It's your responsibility to reduce the code to something that is real code and shows the error and does not have irrelevant stuff in it.

Comment: The code you currently have in the question has regressed to the error about passing the vector by value. Go and make your MCVE before you do anything else and make sure it satisfies M, C, and V.

Comment: I don't see anything in the "Here's the link again" where it says `void main` or `dynamic_cast<Derrived &>`. In fact that page has the correct piece of code `emps[0]->printEmployee();` which for some reason you deleted the `()` off and then (a) posted error messages C2227, and after that (b) mangled the code instead of putting the `()` back.  It's still unclear what problem you are *actually* having, seeing as the "real code" gives  none of these error messages you have quoted.

Comment: Latest iteration of code has no errors apart from the `void main`, please update the title and the associated text to explain what problem you are actually having

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach to using vectors was flawed from the get go, rewrote the project from the ground up using a more rational approach after verifying that there was a typo in the assignment information.